# Организация правильного транслита

Tags: php

Добрый день всем , требуется написать код который правильно переведет с транслита на русский язык. Гуглил но так и не нашел правильный код .. Правильный массив символов для обратного транслита. 
 К примеру - Detskaya odejda , Privet
 Ответ - Детская одежда, привет

Спасибо, огромное за трату времени и сил на мой вопрос.

Comment: это сложный вопрос, все транслитерят как попало. Если вы сами делаете транслитерацию, то сделайте обратную процедуру, это просто

Comment: http://translit.net/ как они это делают?

Comment: translit.net  - что то на подобии замены клавиатуры . Мне нужна не замена а именно перевод.

Comment: Уважаемый **splash58** - на данный момент я не могу определиться какого типа транслит больше используется, что бы решить данный вопрос. С обратным транслитом все понятно.